# onNewIntent is called when app is launched from background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a `singleTop` activity, this activity is launched via `Intent`:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(GCMIntentService.this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

`onNewIntent` is called.

My problem is that then I hit home button, and then launch application again (from background) `onNewIntent` is called again with the same intent, and I can not find a way to discard this `Intent`. 
I tried to `putExtra` flag to this intent, but it is not persisted between application state changes.

Is it possible to stop calling `onNewIntent()` when application comes to foreground?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add the line below to your MainActivity

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```